# Return the first and last element in the list Scheme

Tags: scheme

Pretty straightforward question. My initial approach was to define another procedure to find the last element of lst within first-last. After finding the last element I appended it with the first element of lst (car lst). 
This is how append works. 
(append list1 list2)
    e.g., (append '(1 2 3) '(2 1 5)) -> (1 2 3 2 1 5)
I'm wondering if the problem is just with my syntax but I am not sure.

```
(define (first-last lst)
 (define (last lst)
  (cond ((null? (cdr lst))(car lst))
  (else (last (cdr lst)))))
(append(car lst)(last lst)))
```

The error occurs in the

```
(append(car lst)(last lst)))
```

"mcar: contract violation

expected: mpair?

given: 1"

This is my first question on stack, so I'm sorry if the question is not presented in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is only for *joining* two or more lists. Here, though, you're not joining existing lists, but building a list from two elements. For that, use `list`:

```
(list (car lst) (last lst))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `match`, a neat solution is possible:

```
(define first-last
  (lambda (x)
    (match x
           ((first rest ... last)
            (list first last))
           ((only) (list only only))
           (_ #f))))
```

Of course, you could return something other than `#f` in the catch-all clause.

Comment: `match` is a `#!racket` feature and not a `#!r[56]rs` feature. Since the error mentions `mcar` it's not `#!racket` the OP uses.

Comment: I am using the portable `match` implementation by Alex Shinn (with guile), not the racket `match`. The question itself refers to scheme in general, not a specific implementation, even though you might be able to infer the implementation.